# Pixi JS 7 / Error on PIXI.Assets.load(json)

Tags: 2d, vite, pixi.js

i take this code from Pixi examples ( https://pixijs.io/examples/?v=dev#/sprite/animatedsprite-jet.js ) :

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import json from './assets/fighter.json';

const app = new PIXI.Application({ background: '#1099bb' });
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

PIXI.Assets.load(json).then(() => {
    // create an array of textures from an image path
    const frames = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        const val = i < 10 ? `0${i}` : i;

        // magically works since the spritesheet was loaded with the pixi loader
        frames.push(PIXI.Texture.from(`rollSequence00${val}.png`));
    }

    // create an AnimatedSprite (brings back memories from the days of Flash, right ?)
    const anim = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(frames);

    /*
     * An AnimatedSprite inherits all the properties of a PIXI sprite
     * so you can change its position, its anchor, mask it, etc
     */
    anim.x = app.screen.width / 2;
    anim.y = app.screen.height / 2;
    anim.anchor.set(0.5);
    anim.animationSpeed = 0.5;
    anim.play();

    app.stage.addChild(anim);

    // Animate the rotation
    app.ticker.add(() => {
        anim.rotation += 0.01;
    });
});
```

And in browser console i'm get this message :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Resolver.ts:334:60
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Resolver.add (Resolver.ts:301:51)
    at Assets.ts:407:35
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AssetsClass.load (Assets.ts:403:14)
```

I'm using a Vite(4.0)

I try using path to JSON in PIXI.Assets.load('/assets/fighter.json), is not help me.

But i'm get another message in browser console :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Loader.load] Failed to load http://localhost:5173/assets/fighter.json.
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (at Loader.ts:151:27)
    at Loader.ts:151:27
    at async Promise.all (:5173/index 0)
    at async Loader.load (Loader.ts:156:15)
    at async AssetsClass._mapLoadToResolve (Assets.ts:672:30)
    at async AssetsClass.load (Assets.ts:419:40)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I added CopyPlugin to Webpack. And instead of import json, I give the direct link to the json file ("assets/spine.json")

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: "src/assets", to: "assets"},
      ],
    }),
  ]
}
```

Now that is my spine load:

```js
PIXI.Assets.load("assets/spine.json").then((data) => this.onSpineLoaded(data))

onSpineLoaded(asset) {
    this.player = new Spine(asset.spineData)
    this.addChild(this.player)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the equivalent to the webpack copy plugin for vite https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy

However, you most likely don't need it if you use the Public dir.
Put your json files in the Public directory and they will be served from the root in development and will be copied to the root of your dist/build folder in production. No imports needed

In your case (assuming you moved the json file to Public dir:

```
const json = "/fighter.json"
PIXI.Assets.load(json).then(() => {
...
}
```